# How to Get a value from a text file

Tags: java, string, file, text-files

**My problem** : I need to get several values from a text file.

I am working on a parser from the ttcn-3 language to the XML language and what I need to do is to get some key words and values from the ttcn module which is written in an text file to build the XML file.

**Here is the start of my ttcn code**:

```
module SessionSetup
{
type port InputPortType message { in charstring }
type port OutputPortType message { out charstring }
type component SessionSetupResComponentType {
    port InputPortType InputPort;
    port OutputPortType OutputPort;
}
```

For example I need to get the string which is right after module (SessionSetup) and here is the code I made:

```
public  void ReadTheFileGetTheModuleName(String fichier){
            try{
                InputStream ips=new FileInputStream(fichier); 
                InputStreamReader ipsr=new InputStreamReader(ips);
                BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(ipsr);
                String ligne;

                while ((ligne=br.readLine())!=null){
                    if (ligne.contains("module"))
                    {
                        String[] st = ligne.split(ligne, ' ');
                        System.out.println("Nom = "+st[1]);
                    }

                    chaine+=ligne+"\n";

                }
                br.close();
            }       
            catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println(e.toString());
            }
        }
```

The problem is that it doesn't work, I don't get the string after module.

Thanks

Comment: perhaps try doing it with Scanner, it's not the fastest way but is really easy

Comment: where do you read in the next line? i think you have to add `ligne=br.readLine();` in your while loop and to get not an NPE I would set `ligne="";` and instead of `split`, try using `substring`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 String[] st = ligne.split(ligne, ' ');
                       /\/\/\/\/\/\/\
                 Incorrect way, pass some regex on which string should split
```

Your `String#Split()` method is wrong , Please check the [documentation](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_split.htm)

it should be like this

```
public String[] split(String regex, int limit)

or

public String[] split(String regex)
```

## Note : You will not get a compile time error , Since this  (' ') in split() method is a character and can be implicitly type casted to Integer.